# Clojure - Adding Values in multiple vectors by index

Tags: clojure

I have 3 vectors `[1 2 3]` `[4 5 6]` `[7 8 9`. I want to add the vectors by indices ie return a vector

```
[(+ 1 4 7) (+ 2 5 8) (+ 3 6 9)] => [12 15 18]
```

I thought if doing something like this but I realise I'm not getting the vector out

```
(defn vec-adder [x y z]
  (loop [a 1]
    (when (< a (count x)
      (recur (+ (nth x a) (nth y a) (nth z a)) (+ a 1)))))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(mapv + [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

`+` is a function that can take any number of arguments (it is multi-arity).

Comment: ... or, upon a general sequence of vectors: `#(apply mapv + %)`. For example, `(#(apply mapv + %) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]) => [12 15 18]`.